# How to perform a Single-Class classification with multiple classes in python neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am very new to python and Neural network, after reading through a couple of tutorials, I am trying to create my NN from scratch to learn.

My data is like this:

0.086, 0.4343, 0.42, class1

0.186, 0.4343, 0.55, class2

0.286, 0.4343, 0.42, class2

0.586, 0.4343, 0.42, class3

I wants to create a neural network in python from scratch to predict output class.

After reading this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6), I got some idea. However, in the tutorial, the output is a binary class. So say the prediction result is:

input:0.7 0.3 0.5

Prediction: 0.23

output Class: 0 and 1

**Does it mean that the NN think there is a 77% chance for the output to be 0**?

If that is the case, then what will happen when output class is -1, 0, and 1 and 
the NN's Prediction is 0.23? How can I get the possibility of the prediction belonging to each class? If possible, can someone point me some python tutorials on multiple classes?

Answer (score 0):

For non-binary classification, you can generally choose one of two methods - the [softmax method](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-softmax-function-neural-net-outputs-as-probabilities-and-ensemble-classifiers-9bd94d75932) (generally more popular) or the [one-against-all method](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/one-vs-all).

In the softmax method, your neural network should have 3 output nodes rather than 1. You apply a softmax function to those 3 output nodes and that should give you a probability of being in each class. In this method, the sum of the probabilities output across the 3 output nodes will add up to one.

In the one-against-all method, you would again be training 3 output nodes, but each output node is a binary classifier asking whether this object is in that class or not. I.e. each output node asks the binary question "is this class 1 or not", "is this class 2 or not". You then pick the node that output the highest probability. In this method, the output nodes probabilities will not necessarily add up to one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right that according to your algorithm, there is 77% chance that it belongs to class-0.

Coming to your question on the case with 3 different classes.

Actually, the case that you are asking is one of [multi-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) that arises when there are more than 2 classes. For this case, the neural network is trained to calculate the probability that a certain data sample belongs to a class.

In your case, with 3 classes, the output layer will have 3 neurons and each the value at each node will give you the probability that the data sample belongs to that class.

Now, we get these probabilities from activations of the last layer by using softmax.